# Check if a set of nodes is connected with a given distance

Tags: algorithm, graph, nodes, connectivity

I'm given a set of nodes with their coordinates and a given distance and i was wondering how i could check that all these nodes are connected with this distance (that is, if there exists a path that connects all those points with a maximum edge equal to this distance). The number of nodes can potentially be huge.

I was thinking of DFS / BFS but considering i don't know the distance between nodes (i have to compute them) i was wondering if it was adapted to this situation.

thanks

Comment: You say "maximum edge equal to this distance", but is that the total path length, or a maximum for any single segment of the path? Does it have to be strictly equal, or "less than or equal" or something? Using the usual Euclidian distance, finding an exact match may be only possible with a brute-force exhaustive approach.

Comment: no, it's really the length of the edge. I don't mind about the total path length as long as i know there exists a path that connects all nodes, and this path has its maximum edge inferior or equal to my distance

Comment: I think what you'll need is a minimal spanning tree. If your input distance is larger than all edges in that tree, then any path connecting all the nodes will have an edge no larger than the input distance. If your input distance is less than the longest edge in the spanning tree, then that necessarily disallows that edge, and since the tree is minimal, the result would be disconnected components, so there would be no such path...